# Rails 4.0 Net::HTTPBadResponse wrong status line: "<html>" when doing bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I have a rails app where I want to update my gems, however when I do **bundle update** I get this error

```
Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): Net::HTTPBadResponse wrong status line: "<html>"
Retrying source fetch due to error (3/3): Net::HTTPBadResponse wrong status line: "<html>"
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
```

How do I solve this

Comment: did you `see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues`?

Comment: Yes I have and I've even followed the troubleshooting steps listed there but to no avail

Comment: Can you post your `Gemfile`? Are you required to use an HTTP proxy to reach the Internet?

Comment: Yeah, I was using this GUI ubuntu app called ubproxy to set and unset my proxy settings and turns out that when you unset them you sometimes have to restart your machine to effect the changes